# Unity Mecanim animations for Blender Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, makehuman, three.js

I created this fully rigged character with face blend shapes that I've used for Unity.

I used mecanim animations and lip sync for the character in Unity. Now I want this character doing similar things in WebGL in three.js, using [FBX Loader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx.html). How do I get the Unity animations for my Blender file so I can have the same animations?

Comment: Are you asking how to export FBX from Unity, or from Blender? Do you have all of the animations working in Blender?

Comment: I mean how to export fbx from Unity for Blender. My animation works in Unity. I don't have the animations in Blender at all. The mecanim animations are in Unity, stored with a xxx.fbx.meta file and a obj model file.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I only know about the Blender -> three.js part of this. :)